# Add new rows after a serial number in the first column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to add more rows to table_1 (first column sequence ) from another table_2 under the last first column [NO] from Table_1 
for example

**Table_1**

```
 NO  F1  f2   code   f3   Name 
 --  --  --    --   --    --
1     a   0    22    0    ID
2     b   0    19    0    ID 
3     c   0    10    0    pass
4     d   0    05    0    pass
```

**Table_2** that was imported from excel

```
NO    code     Name 
--     --       --
5      11       ID
6      12       ID 
7      06       pass
8      29       pass
```

My result

```
    NO   F1  f2   code  f3   Name 
    --   --  --    --   --    --
    1     a   0    22    0    ID
    2     b   0    19    0    ID 
    3     c   0    10    0    pass
    4     d   0    05    0    pass
    5     0   0    11    0    ID
    6     0   0    12    0    ID 
    7     0   0    06    0    pass
    8     0   0    29    0    pass
```

Comment: what is the end result desired? nulls for f1 f2 & f3?

Comment: NO  F1  f2   code   f3   Name 
 --  --  --    --   --    --
1     a   0    22    0    ID
2     b   0    19    0    ID 
3     c   0    10    0    pass
4     d   0    05    0    pass

Comment: Please add that to question formatted.

Comment: I add with main question

Comment: Be aware a table has no inherent order.  You will typically get the order rows were added but that is not a given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @MaxID INT = (SELECT MAX([NO]) FROM Table_1)

INSERT INTO Table_1 ([NO], F1, f2, code, f3, Name)
SELECT ( @MaxID + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) ) , 0 , 0, code, 0, Name FROM 
Table_2
```

Comment: I was  tried but i have message 'Incorrect syntax near '0'.'

Answer (score 4):

Made edits based on updated results.

Let me specify what I think you are trying to do:

1. Add all records from table 2 where No is greater than any record in table 1

This will insert and set f1 f2 & f3 to 0:

```
declare @maxNo int = (select max(NO) from t1)

insert into t1 (NO,code,Name,f1, f2,f3)
select NO,code,Name,'0',0,0 from t2
where NO > @maxNo
```

Comment: Not clear he want to use @maxNo like that but still a good answer.